# How to figure out 2 tables situation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to learn hibernate+spring, and now I faced with (maybe common) problem.

Imagine I have 2 models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cars")
public class Cars {

@Column(name="averageSpeed")
private double speed;

/?? 
private List<Type> types;

// setters and getters
}


and Type model:

@Entity
@Table(name="types")
public class Type{

// some variables

   //?//
   private Cars car;

}
```

In this case where you find " //?//" I do not know how to figure it out. What I want to do is to make that car has many Types. It should be OneToMany, but how can I adapt it to this situation?

My current solution:

add to Cars class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="cars")
private List<Type> types;
```

add to Type class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="Typeid")
Cars car;
```

Is this ok? I want to get that Car can have many types. For example If I have car hybrid, so it can be related with 2 types of car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above you should have car not cars as you have used variable car :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="car")
private List<Type> types;

add to Type class:

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="Typeid")
Cars car;
```

and their respective setter and getters.

You can also have for cascading to parent and child table in vice-versa direction like this example :

```
@Entity
public class Car{
  ...
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="car", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<Type> types;
  ...
}
```

Comment: But now, car can have types, but it will look like:
car_id 1 type_id 2
car_id 1 type_id 3
and so on.

It is not ok.
So more better way is to make that Type can have many cars>

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's okay, if you have a 1-n relationship it should work.
TO learn more about JPA/Hibernate I recommend this tutorials:
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/
Take a look in the "Hibernate Association (Table Relationship)" section. It is very explicative.
Hope it helps. Good study.